# Limit number of threads per sidekiq queue

Tags: sidekiq

Is there a way for me to limit the number of maximum threads per sidekiq queue?

For example:

We have a daily job that takes quite a lot of time to get processed. On the one hand we can say let's put 20 threads and get it done faster. Well, no - that clogs up our database.

What I want is to have something similar to:
DailyJobsQueue - 10 threads max, regularJobsQueue - no limit of threads (the rest of available threads - not to say they will be used not in peak times).

I've seen I can give priority to threads that changes the polling for jobs.. But that's not what I need.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sidekiq does not allow you to limit concurrency.

I would put the daily jobs in a low priority queue.  Normal work will still get processed quickly and the daily jobs will be processed by any leftover threads.

Comment: But that means the max threads I need to configure for sidekiq is the max threads I want to allow the daily job to have...  That kinda Sucks...