# How to control concurrency per queue?

Tags: sidekiq

Sidekiq documentation suggests I can only control the global concurrency of sidekiq, rather than per queue. I am raising a question here with hope that there's a solution for a per-queue concurrency setting. Some 3rd party services just won't accept high concurrency, and limiting the entire sidekiq just for those is painful.

I'm on sidekiq 3.3

Answer (score 5):

Using Heroku I was able to control concurrency per queue by setting an environment variable in Procfile and then utilizing it in an `sidekiq.rb` initializer:

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
 config.options[:concurrency] = (ENV['SIDEKIQ_WORKERS_PROCFILE'] || ENV['SIDEKIQ_WORKERS'] || 1).to_i
 ...
end
```

`SIDEKIQ_WORKERS_PROCFILE` is set in Procfile for one queue - other queues use `SIDEKIQ_WORKERS` that is set in Heroku settings.

I'm not sure if this could be anyhow helpful in your scenario though.

UPDATE

To clarify this, **the idea involves deployment on Heroku and every queue is processed in a separate dyno.** This makes it still use global sidekiq concurrency settings, dynos are just a workaround which does the job in my use case.

My `Procfile` looks like this:

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
default: env HEROKU_PROCESS=default bundle exec sidekiq -c 5
important: env HEROKU_PROCESS=important bundle exec sidekiq -q important -c 5
instant: env HEROKU_PROCESS=instant bundle exec sidekiq -q instant -c 5
matrices: env HEROKU_PROCESS=matrices SIDEKIQ_WORKERS_PROCFILE=1 bundle exec sidekiq -q matrices -c 1
```

You can see that the `matrices` worker has `SIDEKIQ_WORKERS_PROCFILE` variable set to 1 - this makes it possible to run the worker with the queue with different concurrency. The variable is read by the `sidekiq.rb` initializer. Please note that there is also the `-c 1` option - I don't know if that matters however.

The initializer is already up there.

All set up and in the sidekiq dashboard I can see that the `matrices` queue is running 1 thread while other use 3 (the `SIDEKIQ_WORKERS` variable is set to 3 in Heroku settings env. variable):

[image]

Comment: I don't see how this is setting concurrency on a specific queue?

Comment: @Dty I'll update response later but `SIDEKIQ_WORKERS_PROCFILE` is set in Procfile for a given queue, like: `important: env HEROKU_PROCESS=important SIDEKIQ_CONCURRENCY=1 bundle exec sidekiq -q important -c 1` while others are like: `instant: env HEROKU_PROCESS=instant bundle exec sidekiq -q instant -c 5`

Comment: Sorry, am I missing something? I still don't see how this specifies concurrency for a **specific** queue. I really want to be able to do this but the sidekiq author said it's not possible back in 2014 here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537799/limit-number-of-threads-per-sidekiq-queue?rq=1

Comment: Thanks so much for clarifying. This might work perfectly for my use case.

Comment: So as far as I understand, that solution is only for heroku ?

Comment: @AdamPiotrowski it was tested only on Heroku, and I guess for other services they would have  to be similar setup in terms of running sidekiq queues as separate instances of the nodes run by  Procfile or similar.

Answer (score 5):

The Enterprise version of Sidekiq has enhanced concurrency control:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Ent-Rate-Limiting

In particular, you can limit concurrency of arbitrary jobs by count or interval. e.g. up to 20 jobs at a time; or up to 20 jobs per (60 seconds/1 hour, etc). The interval can be rolling or clock-aligned.

This could satisfy the per-queue control you're asking about with the correct usage. But it can be much more flexible, controlling concurrency by your own groupings. For example, you could specify up to 30 jobs per second can hit PayPal. Or, you could specify 30 jobs per second per state can hit Paypay, and 15 jobs per state can hit Stripe simultaneously. (Assuming 'state' is an attribute in your data, of course.)

There's no limit to how fine-grained you want to define your groups.

Answer (score 4):

I simply remove concurrency from the yml file and change it when I launch the worker.

sidekiq.yml

```
:queues:
  - default
  - long_running
```

I am running my workers in a docker environment. I just run separate workers for each queue:

Default worker starts with

```
sidekiq -q default -c 5
```

Long running worker starts with

```
sidekiq -q long_running -c 2
```

Alternatively, you could have separate yml configs and use the -C option to pass a different config

Answer (score 1):

To handle the queue wise concurrency you can use this gem [sidekiq-limit-fetch](https://github.com/brainopia/sidekiq-limit_fetch).
which fix the maximum no of threads that queue can use.

Comment: Have you tried? seems it doesn't work.